# How to eliminate duplicate 'NA's and Values in a data.frame R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

How would we take a data.frame like this with duplicate values and 'NA's:

```
IRIS_EXAMPLE <- "Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         NA           1.4         0.2        NA
2          5.1         3.5          NA          0.2        NA
3          NA          NA           1.4         NA         setosa
4          5.1         3.5          NA          NA         setosa
5          5.1         3.5          1.4         NA         NA"
IRIS_EXAMPLE <- read.table(text = IRIS_EXAMPLE, header = TRUE)
```

And **eliminate** duplicate **'NA's** and duplicate **values** to give us something like this:

```
IRIS_EXAMPLE <- "Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2        setosa
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can accomplish this by using `summarise` and `across` from the `dplyr` package. The `first` function is used to extract the first non-NA value.

```r
suppressMessages(library(dplyr))

IRIS_EXAMPLE <- "Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         NA           1.4         0.2        NA
2          5.1         3.5          NA          0.2        NA
3          NA          NA           1.4         NA         setosa
4          5.1         3.5          NA          NA         setosa
5          5.1         3.5          1.4         NA         NA"
IRIS_EXAMPLE <- read.table(text = IRIS_EXAMPLE, header = TRUE)


IRIS_EXAMPLE %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~list(first(.[!is.na(.)]))))

#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I ran the code yesterday and it worked just fine but now today it doesn't work. It will return a table with column names but no data. What type of structure does this need? Would you know why it might not be populating the table? Thanks!

Comment: @J.R.RTolkien are you using the code as it is provided in my solution? Is anything different? If so, please let me know.

Comment: @J.R.RTolkien I've created a chat room we can enter to discuss further - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224606/how-to-eliminate-duplicate-nas-and-values-in-a-data-frame-r

Comment: I am using the code exactly as provided. More info: I am using a data.table that is 603 obs. of 50 varibles. Table consists of data types: 'int', 'chr' and 'logi'. Your code worked on a simple example table made of 3 obs. of 3 variables of just 'ints'.

Comment: Cant join chat room I lack the 'rep' :(

Comment: https://us21.chatzy.com/68506983986240
try and join that

Answer (score 3):

You can remove `NA` values with `na.omit` and select the first `unique` value in each column.

```
do.call(cbind.data.frame, lapply(IRIS_EXAMPLE,function(x) unique(na.omit(x))[1]))

#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

Comment: Hi @Ronak, I am confused as to why:


IRIS_EXAMPLE %>%
na.omit() %>%
unique()

won't work here as well? It seems to work with 3 columns, but when the 4th is added it doesn't.

Comment: `na.omit` will drop rows even if there is one `NA` in it. Since there is one `NA` in each row in `IRIS_EXAMPLE` it drops all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Look at dplyr::coalesce. Fills na elements with non na elements from other vectors. Here vectors are the rows.

[EDIT] Something similar to above but ended up being alot more verbose.  Would recommend above, but for completeness.

> do.call(coalesce,apply(X=as.matrix(IRIS_EXAMPLE),MARGIN=1,FUN=function(x){as.list(x)})%>%map(.f = unlist))

`Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species`

`"5.1"        "3.5"        "1.4"        "0.2"     "setosa"`

Comment: It would be great if you can show your solution with an example

Comment: do.call(coalesce,apply(X=as.matrix(IRIS_EXAMPLE),MARGIN=1,FUN=function(x) {as.list(x)})%>%map(.f = unlist))